# regex for finding href from htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regex pattern for finding web page links in a HTML code I first use . I'm using HTML Agility Packs.
My input is: targeturl.com
My result list consists of url string,like below :

1. #carouselitem
2. http://targeturl.com/news?id=1
3. http://
4. news?id=3
5. mailto:contact@targeturl.com

I just need the number 2 and 4.

Comment: The HTML Agility Pack allows you to access unique nodes within an HTML page. I assume you're looking for any links on the page that have a query string. Is this correct?  If you make your question a bit clearer there are lots of people who can help.  There's also plenty of examples of the HTML Agility Pack in use on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The commonality between the strings 2 and 4 is that they both have a `?` and an `=` character with text between. The `?` comes first later followed by the `=`.

This pattern will match on 2 and 4 only:

`Regex.IsMatch( inputData, @"\?.+=")`